# refer to a variable in a union

Tags: c, tcp, struct, unions

```
typedef struct in_addr {
  union {
    struct {
      u_char s_b1,s_b2,s_b3,s_b4;
    } S_un_b;
    struct {
      u_short s_w1,s_w2;
    } S_un_w;
    u_long S_addr;
  } S_un;
} IN_ADDR, *PIN_ADDR, FAR *LPIN_ADDR;

in_addr srcip
```

a simple `in_addr` structure, i noticed that i can only refer to the S_addr by `srcip.S_addr`, and `srcip.S_un.S_addr` doesnt work. i made a test about this.

```
struct test_struct {
        union {
            int m;
            int n;
        }test;
    };
    test_struct x;
    x.test.m = 1;
```

compile successfuly, but when i change `x.test.m = 1` to `x.m = 1`, compile failed. why those two similar conditions dont accord with each other?

`srcip.S_addr` success, `srcip.S_un.S_addr`  failed

`x.test.m` success, but `x.m` failed, completely different!

USING VS2008 and Win7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To declare the `in_addr` structure in your question, either use the typedef:

```
IN_ADDR srcip;
```

or

```
struct in_addr srcip;
```

Then you should be able to use `srcip.S_un.S_addr`.

By doing `in_addr srcip`, you are probably declaring something else called `in_addr` that is available in the namespace.